Order variable names by custom numeric pattern
I have the following dataset:
df <- structure(list(a3_1_1 = 0, a3_1_2 = 0, a3_1_3 = 0, a3_1_4 = 0, 
    a3_1_5 = 0, a3_1_6 = 0, a3_1_7 = 0, a3_1_8 = 0, a3_1_9 = 0, 
    a3_1_10 = 0, a3_1_11 = 0, a3_1_12 = 0, a3_1_13 = 0, a3_1_14 = 0, 
    a3_1_15 = 0, a3_1_16 = 0, a3_1_17 = 0, a3_2_1 = 0, a3_2_2 = 0, 
    a3_2_3 = 0, a3_2_4 = 0, a3_2_5 = 0, a3_2_6 = 0, a3_2_7 = 0, 
    a3_2_8 = 0, a3_2_9 = 0, a3_2_10 = 0, a3_2_11 = 0, a3_2_12 = 0, 
    a3_2_13 = 0, a3_2_14 = 0, a3_2_15 = 0, a3_2_16 = 0, a3_2_17 = 0, 
    a3_3_1 = 0, a3_3_2 = 0, a3_3_3 = 0, a3_3_4 = 0, a3_3_5 = 0, 
    a3_3_6 = 0, a3_3_7 = 0, a3_3_8 = 0, a3_3_9 = 0, a3_3_10 = 0, 
    a3_3_11 = 0, a3_3_12 = 0, a3_3_13 = 0, a3_3_14 = 0, a3_3_15 = 0, 
    a3_3_16 = 0, a3_3_17 = 0), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")

I have many variables that are part of a table with the same variable name's number pattern. I'm looking for a certain arrangement: the second number should be arranged as a group inside the last number. That way, I would like to make a function that takes the first and the last variable as arguments and arranges them in such a way. The desired output should be this:
ordered_df <- structure(list(a3_1_1 = 0, a3_2_1 = 0, a3_3_1 = 0, a3_1_2 = 0, 
    a3_2_2 = 0, a3_3_2 = 0, a3_1_3 = 0, a3_2_3 = 0, a3_3_3 = 0, 
    a3_1_4 = 0, a3_2_4 = 0, a3_3_4 = 0, a3_1_5 = 0, a3_2_5 = 0, 
    a3_3_5 = 0, a3_1_6 = 0, a3_2_6 = 0, a3_3_6 = 0, a3_1_7 = 0, 
    a3_2_7 = 0, a3_3_7 = 0, a3_1_8 = 0, a3_2_8 = 0, a3_3_8 = 0, 
    a3_1_9 = 0, a3_2_9 = 0, a3_3_9 = 0, a3_1_10 = 0, a3_2_10 = 0, 
    a3_3_10 = 0, a3_1_11 = 0, a3_2_11 = 0, a3_3_11 = 0, a3_1_12 = 0, 
    a3_2_12 = 0, a3_3_12 = 0, a3_1_13 = 0, a3_2_13 = 0, a3_3_13 = 0, 
    a3_1_14 = 0, a3_2_14 = 0, a3_3_14 = 0, a3_1_15 = 0, a3_2_15 = 0, 
    a3_3_15 = 0, a3_1_16 = 0, a3_2_16 = 0, a3_3_16 = 0, a3_1_17 = 0, 
    a3_2_17 = 0, a3_3_17 = 0), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")

The solution I'm looking for should use dplyr::arrange, but I'm obviously open to suggestions.
my_arranger <- function(df, from = col1, to = col2){
df %>% arrange({{col1}}:{{col2}}) #Here should make the above requested arrangement
}


You can try the code below
nms <- names(df)

d2 <- as.integer(gsub(".*_(\\d+)_.*", "\\1", nms))
d3 <- as.integer(gsub(".*_(\\d+)$", "\\1", nms))

nms[order(d3, d2)]


Assuming they are all starting with a. You could try strsplit
> df[as.data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(substring(names(df), 2), '_'))) |> 
+      type.convert(as.is=TRUE) |> 
+      with(order(V3, V1, V2))]
  a3_1_1 a3_2_1 a3_3_1 a3_1_2 a3_2_2 a3_3_2 a3_1_3 a3_2_3 a3_3_3 a3_1_4 a3_2_4 a3_3_4 a3_1_5 a3_2_5 a3_3_5 a3_1_6
1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  a3_2_6 a3_3_6 a3_1_7 a3_2_7 a3_3_7 a3_1_8 a3_2_8 a3_3_8 a3_1_9 a3_2_9 a3_3_9 a3_1_10 a3_2_10 a3_3_10 a3_1_11 a3_2_11
1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0       0
  a3_3_11 a3_1_12 a3_2_12 a3_3_12 a3_1_13 a3_2_13 a3_3_13 a3_1_14 a3_2_14 a3_3_14 a3_1_15 a3_2_15 a3_3_15 a3_1_16
1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
  a3_2_16 a3_3_16 a3_1_17 a3_2_17 a3_3_17
1       0       0       0       0       0

or scan
> df[as.data.frame(t(matrix(scan(text=substring(names(df), 2), sep='_', qui=T), 3))) |> 
+      with(order(V3, V1, V2))]
  a3_1_1 a3_2_1 a3_3_1 a3_1_2 a3_2_2 a3_3_2 a3_1_3 a3_2_3 a3_3_3 a3_1_4 a3_2_4 a3_3_4 a3_1_5 a3_2_5 a3_3_5 a3_1_6
1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  a3_2_6 a3_3_6 a3_1_7 a3_2_7 a3_3_7 a3_1_8 a3_2_8 a3_3_8 a3_1_9 a3_2_9 a3_3_9 a3_1_10 a3_2_10 a3_3_10 a3_1_11 a3_2_11
1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0       0
  a3_3_11 a3_1_12 a3_2_12 a3_3_12 a3_1_13 a3_2_13 a3_3_13 a3_1_14 a3_2_14 a3_3_14 a3_1_15 a3_2_15 a3_3_15 a3_1_16
1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
  a3_2_16 a3_3_16 a3_1_17 a3_2_17 a3_3_17
1       0       0       0       0       0


We can extract two group of numbers using str_extract and capture it in dataframe and order the data to get index of correct column numbers.
order_cols <- stringr::str_extract(names(df),  
                 'a\\d+_(\\d+)_(\\d+)', group = c(1, 2)) |>
  data.frame() |> 
  type.convert(as.is = FALSE) |>
  rev() |>
  do.call(order, args = _)

df[order_cols]

# a3_1_1 a3_2_1 a3_3_1 a3_1_2 a3_2_2 a3_3_2 a3_1_3 a3_2_3 a3_3_3 a3_1_4 a3_2_4
#      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
#  a3_3_4 a3_1_5 a3_2_5 a3_3_5 a3_1_6 a3_2_6 a3_3_6 a3_1_7 a3_2_7 a3_3_7 a3_1_8
#      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
#  a3_2_8 a3_3_8 a3_1_9 a3_2_9 a3_3_9 a3_1_10 a3_2_10 a3_3_10 a3_1_11 a3_2_11 a3_3_11
#      0      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0       0       0
#  a3_1_12 a3_2_12 a3_3_12 a3_1_13 a3_2_13 a3_3_13 a3_1_14 a3_2_14 a3_3_14 a3_1_15
#       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
#  a3_2_15 a3_3_15 a3_1_16 a3_2_16 a3_3_16 a3_1_17 a3_2_17 a3_3_17
#       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0


Using arrange and selecting 2 numbers from the column name pattern to arrange by
library(dplyr)

reord <- function(df, num1, num2) {
  data.frame(t(sapply(strsplit(names(df), "_"), unlist))) %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  arrange(across(c(!!num2, !!num1), as.numeric)) %>% 
  select(n) %>% unlist()}

output when applied
df[,reord(df, 2, 3)]
  a3_1_1 a3_2_1 a3_3_1 a3_1_2 a3_2_2 a3_3_2 a3_1_3 a3_2_3 a3_3_3 a3_1_4 a3_2_4
1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  a3_3_4 a3_1_5 a3_2_5 a3_3_5 a3_1_6 a3_2_6 a3_3_6 a3_1_7 a3_2_7 a3_3_7 a3_1_8
1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
  a3_2_8 a3_3_8 a3_1_9 a3_2_9 a3_3_9 a3_1_10 a3_2_10 a3_3_10 a3_1_11 a3_2_11
1      0      0      0      0      0       0       0       0       0       0
  a3_3_11 a3_1_12 a3_2_12 a3_3_12 a3_1_13 a3_2_13 a3_3_13 a3_1_14 a3_2_14
1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
  a3_3_14 a3_1_15 a3_2_15 a3_3_15 a3_1_16 a3_2_16 a3_3_16 a3_1_17 a3_2_17
1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
  a3_3_17
1       0

